# From file stream to assoc-list in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, file-read, clos

I have a file that starts with
        `(defparameter *myfile* 
        '(((KEY 1) (A1 CAN) (A2 4)
            (SUR (((BCZ S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR FS) (LADOM ALL)
            (((NNEW S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR BS) (LADOM ALL)
            ((NNEW NP) (FEATS ((BIG NOM)))))))
            (SEM (LAM P (P "CAN"))) (PARAM 1.0))
          ((KEY 2) (A1 KEDIYI) (A2 4)`...........and goes on like this.

I am guessing this is a CLOS but it is stored in a file. I need to be able to get this data in an assoc-list to reach the A1 or A2 etc. as keys to obtain their values afterwards. What I do now is reading the file line by line and do string operations on it. But I think it is really a bad practice. Here is my code for now;

```
(defun open_ded (path)
 (defvar last_id 0)
 (let ((in (open path :if-does-not-exist nil)))
  (when in
    (loop for line = (read-line in nil)
        while line 
            do 
                (if (setq key_id (findkeyid line)) ;search "KEY" and return its id value
                (setq last_id key_id)) ;if it is not nil, set it to last_id
```

And I know that I can get the whole file with (defparameter *s* (open "path")) but the when I want to do (assoc 'A1 (read *s*)) or (assoc 'KEY (read *s*)) it gets me nowhere. Do you have any ideas about how to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly is in the file?  The `defparameter` form or the form starting with `(((KEY 1) …`?

Comment: @Svante yes it starts from the defparameter part, it is like you are defining a defparameter all together but it is in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in function `load` to read the file:

```
(load "/tmp/data.lisp")
```

This will set variable `*myfile*` so you can then do:

```
* (print *myfile*)

(((KEY 1) (A1 CAN) (A2 4)
  (SUR
   (((BCZ S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR FS) (LADOM ALL)
    (((NNEW S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR BS) (LADOM ALL)
     ((NNEW NP) (FEATS ((BIG NOM)))))))
  (SEM (LAM P (P "CAN"))) (PARAM 1.0))
 ((KEY 2) (A1 KEDIYI) (A2 4)))
(((KEY 1) (A1 CAN) (A2 4)
  (SUR
   (((BCZ S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR FS) (LADOM ALL)
    (((NNEW S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR BS) (LADOM ALL)
     ((NNEW NP) (FEATS ((BIG NOM)))))))
  (SEM (LAM P (P "CAN"))) (PARAM 1.0))
 ((KEY 2) (A1 KEDIYI) (A2 4)))

* (loop for i from 0
        for entry in *myfile*
        do (format t "Entry #~D: ~S~%" i entry))
Entry #0: ((KEY 1) (A1 CAN) (A2 4)
             (SUR
              (((BCZ S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR FS) (LADOM ALL)
               (((NNEW S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR BS) (LADOM ALL)
                ((NNEW NP) (FEATS ((BIG NOM)))))))
             (SEM (LAM P (P "CAN"))) (PARAM 1.0))
Entry #1: ((KEY 2) (A1 KEDIYI) (A2 4))
NIL

* (dolist (entry *myfile*)
     (print (assoc 'key entry)))

(KEY 1)
(KEY 2)
NIL
```

If you don't trust the file contents, and you want to *read* the source code in the file but not *execute* it (which `load` does), you would use `read`. In that case also bind `*read-eval*` to `nil` to safeguard against uses of `#.` that would otherwise execute code while being read:

```
(with-open-file (f "/tmp/data.lisp")
  (let ((*read-eval* nil))
    (loop for form = (read f nil nil)
          while form
          do (print form)))
```

The file contents looks like a collection of entries, with each entry a list of key-value pairs. There is nothing in it that connects it to CLOS, although you could define a structure or class named `entry` with slot names `key`, `bcz`, `feats` et cetera and then use accessors like `(entry-bcz x)` instead of `(second (assoc 'bcz x))`. This might help readability and efficiency, but to do that you need to create objects from this list-based data representation.

Comment: thank you for your time, this was what I was looking for. A program generates this file and it is always like this structure so I can trust the contents. I guess I will try to create a class and then objects to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

@zut showed nicely how to read a file without evaluating the content.

I am using this and showing you how to get from the first expression the key-value pairs.

```
;; read-in-first-expression from file
(defparameter *f* (with-open-file (f "~/Dropbox/cl/test-file.lisp")
            (let ((*read-eval* nil))
              (loop for form = (read f nil nil)
                        while form
                collect form))))
*f*
;; first expression (defparameter expression):
(defparameter *f-1st-expr* (first *f*))
*f-1st-expr*

;; ;; I was trying to get to the data part of the first expression trying/using:
;; (first (second (third *f-1st-expr*)))
;; (second (second (third *f-1st-expr*)))

;; let's say these are lists of small lists of length 2

(defun two-element-lists-to-alist (two-list)
  (mapcar (lambda (p) (cons (first p)
                (let ((el (cdr p)))
                  (if (and (atom (car el)) (= (length el) 1))
                  (car el)
                  el))))
      two-list))

(defun convert-to-alists (read-in-defparameter-expression)
  (let ((data (second (third read-in-defparameter-expression))))
    (mapcar #'two-element-lists-to-alist data)))

;; convert to list of alists
(defparameter *alists* (convert-to-alists *f-1st-expr*))

;; ;; one can now access within the list of a lists using assoc and elt
;; ;; the key-value pairs
;; (assoc 'KEY (elt *alists* 0))
;; (assoc 'KEY (elt *alists* 1))
;; (assoc 'A1  (elt *alists* 0))

;; write a function to directly access key-value-pair of nth alist in alists
(defun get-key-from-nth (alists key nth)
  (assoc key (elt alists nth)))

;; testing:
(get-key-from-nth *alists* 'A1 0) ;; (A1 . CAN)
(get-key-from-nth *alists* 'A1 1) ;; (A1 . KEDIYI)
(get-key-from-nth *alists* 'KEY 0) ;; (KEY . 1)
(get-key-from-nth *alists* 'KEY 1) ;; (KEY . 2)
;; works!
```

The content of `~/Dropbox/cl/test-file.lisp` is:

```
    (defparameter *myfile* 
    '(((KEY 1) (A1 CAN) (A2 4)
        (SUR (((BCZ S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR FS) (LADOM ALL)
        (((NNEW S) (FEATS NIL)) (DIR BS) (LADOM ALL)
        ((NNEW NP) (FEATS ((BIG NOM)))))))
        (SEM (LAM P (P "CAN"))) (PARAM 1.0))
      ((KEY 2) (A1 KEDIYI) (A2 4) 'and-so-on)))
```

Comment: this is great thank you. Wish I could set two answers at the same time.

Comment: Welcome! @Karavana - I'm happy if I could help you!)